# Go from multiple rasters to R compatible table

Tags: raster, r

I have a set of geocoded, pixel-aligned rasters which I would like to use in a model in [R](http://www.r-project.org/). I would like to produce a table of data that can be imported to R, in which there are as many columns as rasters, and as many rows as points at which data is extracted from the rasters. Say I have 3 rasters: r1, r2, r3. I would end up with a table that has r1, r2, r3 as the column headers. The rows would be point1, point2, point3 - and there would be as many rows as points in the layer used to define which points to extract data from. Forgive the bad table:

------r1---r2---r3

point1-1----4---2

point2-4----3---1

How can I do this? I've tried some Arc tools but they have failed or hung. I can use QGIS, Arc or Idrisi.

Is the [Raster package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/) for R a good approach?

Comment: Would you rather simply import a raster into R and then do your raster analysis?  So I better understand your goal, could you please clarify "...as many columns as rasters, and as many rows as pixels"?

Comment: I should have used the word 'point' rather than 'pixel'.

Say I have 5 rasters: r1, r2, r3 etc

I would end up with a table that has r1, r2, r3, r4, r5 as the column headers. The rows would be point1, point2, point3 - and there would be as many rows as points in the layer used to define which points to extract data from. I originally tried to draw the table to exemplify what I mean, but couldn't get the formatting right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are after is:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

s <- stack('r1.tif', 'r2.tif', 'r3.tif')
d <- values(s)
```

Avoid exporting grids to ascii, that only slows things down, and you loose information on the coordinate reference system.

Comment: Great, thanks - this produces the same results as the ASCII route given by whuber, but cuts out all the conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `Raster`.  Here is an example using five coincident raster objects `r.a` ... `r.e`. In practice, you would read these from (say) ASCII exports of the grids:

```
data <- vapply(list(r.a,r.b,r.c,r.d,r.e), "[", rep(0.0, ncol(r.a)*nrow(r.a)))
```

The purpose of the "0.0" is to indicate you want an array of floats.  If the data are integral, use an integer for this value instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I go from my geoTIFF rasters to objects r.a, r.b loaded in R?

Reading the [Raster description](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf), I thought rasterStack sounded promising.

Comment: Several solutions for reading Arc* grids are given at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16720/. I found this by searching the site for the ["R" and "Raster" tags](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raster+r): you may find the other hits useful, too.

Comment: Thanks, I've just finished reading all that - it was lazy of me to ask before searching myself! Other useful things in the 'related' column

Comment: No problem--please just remember to vote up the useful answers (and the questions that prompted them, too)!